# Distinctness of quadratic surd continued fraction convergent ratio limit

Tags: nt.number-theory, continued-fractions

In [this question on math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2808240/64809) I have made two conjectures the first of which I have proved. The second has not been settled. I post it here to seek a proof.

---

Given a quadratic surd $\sqrt d$ where $d$ is a natural number and not a perfect square. $(c_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ is the sequence of convergents of the continued fraction of $x$. Let $r_i:=\frac{c_{i+1}-\sqrt d}{c_i-\sqrt d},\,\forall i\in\mathbf N$. Let $n$ be the period of the continued fraction. [It has been shown](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2813942/64809) $\exists \,l_r:=\lim_\limits{i\rightarrow\infty}r_{in+r},\, \forall r\in\{0,1,\cdots,n-1\}$. Is the following statement, suggested by a numerical experiment, true?

1. For $n\le 2$, $l_0=l_1$.
2. For $n\ge 3$, there exists at least two distinct $l_r$'s.

Answer (score 1):

Proof to conjecture $1.$:

Define
$$P(x):=\frac{\lfloor\sqrt d\rfloor x+d}{x+\lfloor\sqrt d\rfloor}.$$
Obviously $P_d(\sqrt d)=\sqrt d$.

By Theorem Plus of [*Square Root, Continued Fractions and the Orbit of $\frac10$ on $\partial H^2$* by Julian Rose, Krishna Shankar and Justin Thomas](http://www2.math.ou.edu/~shankar/research/cfrac.pdf). The continued fraction of $\sqrt d$ is of period at most $2$ iff $P^i(\infty)=c_i$ for all convergents $\{c_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$.

$$\frac{P(c_i)-P(\sqrt d)}{c_i-\sqrt d}=-\frac{\sqrt d-\lfloor\sqrt d\rfloor}{c_i+\lfloor\sqrt d\rfloor}.$$
So
$$l_0=l_1=-\frac{\sqrt d-\lfloor\sqrt d\rfloor}{\sqrt d+\lfloor\sqrt d\rfloor}.$$